# Intellij not recognising symbols in Maven POM

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm working with a project that has, historically, been supported and developed in an Eclipse environment.  I'm hoping to move this over to Intellij, and I'm currently using the full (Ultimate) package.

There are a few intricacies of the build process that don't appear to be working, which relate to selectively building the resources for the project.  I could work around this, but would rather try and understand why IntelliJ and Eclipse are building the same project in a slightly different way.

I've noticed in my parent POM that the following code has an issue:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.js</include>
                    </includes>
                    <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Intellij is saying `element includes is not allowed here' and it`cannot resolve symbol 'include'`.

As far as I can see, the declarations are valid and in the correct place, and maven appears to be set up as required with the maven plugins installed as required too.  The POM uses the http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd schema.

This kind of stuff has generally been left untouched for a number of years, but I can't see why it is having issues with this particular symbol/declaration?

As above, I've checked the plugins, Maven settings, all the usual suspects.  Another of the plugins uses `<excludes>` with no errors, which makes it a bit more of a puzzle to me?

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is a bug in IDE. You can try to update to last stable version.
[similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606009/intellij-not-recognising-symbols-in-maven-pom)

Comment: Sorry, wanted to add this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996128/maven-jetty-plugin-daemon-element-not-allowed-here)

Comment: Is the issue only in error highlighting or it does prevent you from using the plugin in IDE?

Comment: Thanks for the above - it may well be behaving as expected, as I haven't yet determined the area which is causing the problem.  It seemed prudent to start with the 'errors' first, and so if this is just a, IntelliJ bug then I will overlook it for now.  Thanks