# How to resolve SpringBoot Repackaging Failed?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, multi-module, parent-pom

I am currently following a tutorial with SpringBoot using multi module. However when i try to do **package** this returns the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project pet-clinic-data: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to put something like this on my parent pom file:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>guru.springframework.sfgpetclinic.SfgPetClinicApplication</start-class>
</properties>
```

but this throws another error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project pet-clinic-web: There are test failures.
```

and this is build on one of the module **pet-clinic-data**:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Edit!

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SfgPetClinicApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: there are test class failures. You either have to fix the tests or skip them temporarily. You tag `skip` is incorrect. it should be `<skipTests>`

Comment: It says: **Element Skip Test is not allowed here**

Comment: which IDE are you running ?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: see this answer IntelliJ has problems in past with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996128/maven-jetty-plugin-daemon-element-not-allowed-here you might as well try command line build

Comment: even though I am using 2019.1.2 version?

Comment: Simply fix your tests...

Comment: So far there is no much code on the test, i updated the code above.

Comment: Try mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage. Some related question can be found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488093/execution-default-of-goal-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-maven-plugin1-0

Comment: where does the "main-class" property come from? It looks that property is not known. You can set the mainClass in the configuration section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#mainClass